# alphalens.utils returns KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex (['<dates>, dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)] are in the [index]"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to run sentiment analysis on 10K financial statements and have encountered an error using the following operation:

```
data = al.utils.get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns(cs_df.stack(), pricing.loc[cs_df.index], quantiles=5, bins=None, periods=[1])
```

It returns the following KeyError when I `print(data)`:

```
KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-01', '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)] are in the [index]"
```

The relevant code block:

```
import alphalens as al

factor_data = {}
skipped_sentiments = []

for sentiment in sentiments:
    cs_df = cosine_similarities_df[(cosine_similarities_df['sentiment'] == sentiment)]
    cs_df = cs_df.pivot(index='date', columns='ticker', values='value')

    try:
        data = al.utils.get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns(cs_df.stack(), pricing.loc[cs_df.index], quantiles=5, bins=None, periods=[1])
        factor_data[sentiment] = data

    except:
        skipped_sentiments.append(sentiment)
```

Which when ran just prints all my sentiments as skipped as it is skipping to the `except:` section of the for loop.

My DataFrame `cs_df` looks as follows after the pivot operation:

```
ticker           AMZN
date                 
2012-01-01 0.99706919
2013-01-01 0.99931987
2014-01-01 0.99841510
2015-01-01 0.99805389
2016-01-01 0.99884780
2017-01-01 0.96819148
2018-01-01 0.99957861
2019-01-01 0.99767198
```

Within the for loop i've tried creating a new column with the date index and mapping it into the `al.utils` where `pricing.loc[cs_df.index]` is changed to `pricing.loc[cs_df.date]` line to no avail using `cs_df['date'] = cs_df.index`
I've also tried removing column and index names with:

```
cs_df.columns.name = None
cs_df.index.name = None
```

Renaming the column and index yield the following Dataframe however still returns the same error

```
                 AMZN
2012-01-01 0.99706919
2013-01-01 0.99931987
2014-01-01 0.99841510
2015-01-01 0.99805389
2016-01-01 0.99884780
2017-01-01 0.96819148
2018-01-01 0.99957861
2019-01-01 0.99767198
```

Resetting the index with `cs_df = cs_df.reset_index(drop=True)` doesn't help either and just gets rid of my dates.
Fairly sure that the problem exists with how I'm using the `al.utils` operation and I don't think the pivot causes the issue. Any ideas? Appreciate your help and time!

```
FULL TRACEBACK
---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~FinancialReportSentimentAnalysis.py", line 514, in <module>
    print(al.utils.get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns(cs_df.stack(), pricing.loc[cs_df.index], quantiles=5, bins=None, periods=[1]))
  File "~opt/anaconda3/envs/workspace/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 879, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "~opt/anaconda3/envs/workspace/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1099, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "~opt/anaconda3/envs/workspace/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1037, in _getitem_iterable
    keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis, raise_missing=False)
  File "~opt/anaconda3/envs/workspace/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1254, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "~opt/anaconda3/envs/workspace/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1298, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-01', '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)] are in the [index]"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling onto this.

The problem lies with matching the dates in the financial documents with the dates in the pricing datasheet. As I was trying to match the first day of the year (new years day) and the markets being closed and no pricing data existing for this day there could be no match. So I changed my data to monthly to get aggregated price data for the 1st of January YYYY.

`pricing.loc[cs_df.index]` is where the problem stemmed from.